# Prestashop: how to add shipping cost and show in the invoice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm working with a Prestashop 1.6.1.12 module where I need to add a checkbox to the shipping step of the checkout to allow the customer to rent a special equipment with the delivery. So if the customer checks it I need to add a cost in the invoice. I managed to add the checkbox using the `displayCarrierList` hook and I can check if the customer selected it with the `actionCarrierProcess`.

My question is what is the best way to add this value to the order/invoice and how can I show this information on the invoice? I know I can use the `displayPDFInvoice` hook to add HTML to the invoice, but is it the way I should be doing it? And for the value, should I just add to the shipping cost?

My question is more about best practices.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Separate cost should be displayed in the invoice if customer rent a special equipment. It will provide customer better idea for their cost.

If you add that cost to the shipping cost then customer have no better idea for all cost involved.